# Being specific with Try / Catch

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Being new to programming I have only just found out that you can specifically catch certain types of errors and tie code to only that type of error.

I've been researching into the subject and I don't quite understand the syntax e.g.

```
catch (InvalidCastException e) 
 {
 }
```

I understand the `InvalidCastException` is the type of error being handled, however I am unsure of what `e` is.

Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Just set a breakpoint inside that `catch` block and look at `e` in the debugger!!

Comment: Better look at the MSDN Exception Class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: While this question doesn't show a whole *lot* of research effort, it *is* a very clear and useful question for many people, so I'd recommend not to downvote.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `e` is the object that holds the data specific to the exception.  If you look into different types of exceptions, you'll see that they all have different type of data.  Many don't, but many do, and when they do, they can help you identify just exactly what happened instead of just getting a generic error.

For example, the `NotFiniteNumberException` defines an additional property called `OffendingNumber` that isn't present in a normal `Exception` object...  This then provides additional data that you might need to figure out exactly what happened.

Answer (score 20):

Suppose there was no `e`. How would you obtain the message of the exception?

The name `e` (or any other name) is there for you to get a handle on the exception object so that you can extract information from it.

It is legal syntax not to give out any name:

```
catch (InvalidCastException) //legal C#
```

This works, but you can't know anything else about the error except its type.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that you could declare a catch without a variable... I shall immediately begin littering my code with this. :-p

Answer (score 6):

`"e"` is just whatever you decide to call the exception. just like you would do

```
string name = "...";
```

or

```
int total = 8;
```

where `string` and `int` in this example are the datatypes, (in your case the datatype is `InvalidCastException`) while "`name`" and "`total`" are the variable names, which in your case is just "`e`".

Answer (score 5):

The `'e'` is just the variable name, you could call it `'ex'` or `'exception'` if you find that easier to read. But `'e'` is just a convention, like 'i' in a `for i = 0...` construct

Answer (score 4):

`e` is the variable that the instance of `InvalidCastException` is placed into. You can then view the properties of that object to help you understand exactly what caused the error to be thrown by the code in the `try` block.

Answer (score 4):

"InvalidCastException" is the type, e is the object of this type.
with the object, you can invoke member functions on it. for example

```
catch (InvalidCastException e) {
    ...
    e.printErrorMessage();
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`e` is the reference to the exception object that stores the details of the exception that was caught. The details may include an exception `Message`, an `InnerException` object, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`e` is a variable name. It can be whatever you'd like to name it, such as `exception`.

Answer (score 2):

`e` is the variable that holds the exception so now you can do things like `e.message` and such

Answer (score 2):

e is the instance of the InvalidCastException type.  In the catch block, you can for example say Debug.Write(e.ToString()).